# Updating to database using ajax/jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I’m having trouble using ajax to make an update to my database. Basically I have the jQuery number spinner and when the user clicks up that number for that product is meant to be uploaded to the database. Instead either all the products are updated to that number or the last one is. How can I make it so only the product the user is changing be changed in the database?

It’s worth noting that I’m a total noob at jQuery/ajax but I’m trying to learn.

Twig/HTML:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

<h1 class="text-center"><u><i>Your Cart</i></u></h1>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="who_is_logged_in">
            {% if user is null %}
                <a href="{{ path ('fos_user_security_login') }}">Login</a>
            {% else %}
                <u>Hello<strong> {{ user }}</strong></u>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Price Per Unit</th>    
                    <th>Remove Product</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            {% for key, product in quantity %}  
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ product.product }}</td> <!--Product-->
                        <td>
                            <input class="spinner" value="{{ product.quantity }}" style="width:30px">
                        </td> <!--Quantity-->
                        <td>${{ product.product.price|default('') }}</td> <!--Price-->   
                        <td>
                            <a href="{{ path('product_remove', {'id': product.product.id }) }}">
                                <button name="REMOVE" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="removeButton">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                </button>
                            </a>
                        </td><!--Remove--> 
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}      
            </tbody>
        </table> <!--top table-->

            <div class="money-container">
                <p class="text-right">Total Cost: ${{ totalCostOfAllProducts }}</p>
            </div> <!--moneyContainer-->

        {% for flash_message in app.session.flashbag.get('notice') %}
            <div class="flash-notice">
                <strong>{{ flash_message }}</strong>
            </div> <!--flashNotice-->
        {% endfor %}

    </div> <!--container-->

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('product') }}">
                Add More Products
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('product_bought') }}">
                Buy These Products
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>


    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(".spinner").spinner();
        $('input.spinner').on('spinstop', function(){
            min: 0
            console.log('spinner changed');
            var $this = $(this);
            var value = $('.spinner').val();
            var request = $.ajax({
                url: "{{ path('product_quantityUpdate') }}",
                method: "POST",
                data : {
                    quantity: this.value,
                }
            }).done(function(result){
                console.log('success', result);
            }).error(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr.status);
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(thrownError);
            });
        });
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

Relavent Controller Functions:

```
/**
 * Updates quantity using ajax/jQuery request from showCart twig file
 *
 * @Route("/quantityUpdate", name="product_quantityUpdate")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template()
 */
public function quantityUpdateAction(Request $request) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $cart = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:UserCart')->findOneBy(['user' => $this->getUser(), 'submitted' => false]);

    $productsInUsersCart = $cart->getQuantities();

    foreach ($productsInUsersCart as $key => $value) {

        $productsInUsersCart = $value->getQuantity();   // Within the loop, gets the quantity of the product being changed
            $value->getProduct()->getId();     //SHOULD be the product ID
            $value->getUserCart()->getId();   //SHOULD be the user's cart ID

/* ----------------------------- Like Below & Will Update EVERYTHING in Users Cart ----------------------------- */

    // dump($request->get('id_value'));
    // dump($request->get('prodId')); die;
        $value->setQuantity($_POST['quantity']);
        $em->persist($value);
        $em->flush();
    }

/* ----------------------------- Like Below & Will Update the LAST product in Users Cart ----------------------------- */

        // $value->setQuantity($_POST['quantity']);
        // $em->persist($value);
        // $em->flush();

    return new Response ("This has been successful!");
}
```

Comment: You have to associate the action with the current row, Without your actual HTML output I cannot tell you what to associate the action with, but there is a way to uniquely identify each row,

Comment: I figured this but it's what I'm struggling with. I will add my HTML in an edit. I struggle because the row is an id that I don't know how to retrieve in my ajax.

Answer (score 0):

var id_value = $(this).val().id; // val() without parameters returns value of the input element

To access id you need to write it as

var id_value = $(this).attr('id');// this will return attribute id value from element

Note: **this** is used to point to current element

Comment: thanks for your help again however this doesn't work. I made an edit to show HTML

Comment: If you have solved the problem then it's fine but I would say solve the problem instead of finding workarounds:)

Answer (score 0):

add product id to your input.spinner by adding `data-name=""` or `id=""`
then to access it use `$(selector).attr('id');` or `$(selector).data(name);`

```
<input class="spinner" data-pid="{{product.product.id}}" value="{{product.quantity}}" style="width:30px">
```

then update your function

```
$('input.spinner').on('spinstop', function(){
    min: 0
    console.log('spinner changed');

    var value = $(this).val();
    var productId = $(this).data('pid');

    var request = $.ajax({
            url: "{{ path('product_quantityUpdate') }}",
            method: "POST",
            data : {
                quantity: value,
                id: productId
            }
        }).done(function(result){
            console.log('success', result);
        }).error(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(thrownError);
        });
}
```

this will send quantity and id to your php script, in this case you're updating existing row so you don't need loops, just retrieve single row modify it and store in DB

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$cart = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:UserCart')->findOneBy(['user' => $this->getUser(), 'id' => $request->request->get('id'), 'submitted' => false]);
$cart->setQuantity($request->request->get('quantity'));
$em->persist($cart);
$em->flush();
```